# How to create a new partition from the existing partition?

Tags: partitioning

I wanna create a new partition from the existing root partition.My root partition is about 250GB.I wanna create a new partition say 150 GB taking space from this root partition.Can anyone help me with the procedure on doing this?

`output: fdisk -l`

```
karthick@karthick:~$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for karthick: 

Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x28219744

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          61      487424   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              61       30395   243650561    5  Extended
/dev/sda5              61         124      498688   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6             124         186      498688   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7             186       30395   242651136   83  Linux
```

Comment: At the very least you'll need to get into a state where this isn't the active partition. That means a LiveCD or USB to most people.

Comment: @Oli Yeah i know that,but how to do that using a live CD?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boot from the livecd and run gparted.  You also appear to have duplicate swap partitions so you should get rid of one of those.

Comment: When i boot from a live CD,the resize option is greyed out.

Comment: @karthick87 unmount the swap partitions ( right click )