# How to make separate partition from partition where I mounted /home?

Tags: partitioning, mount

/(root) --> kubuntu installed(20gb)

/Home-----> 200gb where I store my anime and study stuff

I want to make another 100gb partition(to store something pornsel sorry personal) from partition in which /home is mounted.

Note-I have only one HDD of 220gb so I used 20gb for /root (OS) and 200gb for /home

**Without losing data** in home partition it contains my study stuff

Comment: Backup your system, boot a *live* system (eg. (K)Ubuntu installation media) & change your partition(s) as you want, then edit your *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab` or your installed system, not the *live* system that is running) to mount the newly created partition when you want & boot. If you moved your / partition (b/c of resize etc) you may get errors, if so you can then reboot *live* media & fix that, but that's only a risk (depending on how you re-partition your data, thus I'd ignore it & deal only if it's a problem as chances are it won't be)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: Not sure what value this would provide. Slicing up a partition as though it were a directory is suboptimal. If there are things you want to keep from prying eyes, perhaps an encrypted volume would work better. This would grow as required, and it would also be portable, meaning you could move it to a USB device in the future if you chose to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new partition from the existing partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34688/how-to-create-a-new-partition-from-the-existing-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps KDE Partition Manager would be the answer to your question. It allows you to resize without losing data and create new partitions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a disk image in your `/home` partition, Gnome Disks may help you:

1. Open Gnome Disks, choose "New Disk Image" from the left-hand side option list. [image: New Disk Image]

   ---
2. Set the size, name, and the father directory of the disk image, then choose "Attach Disk Image". [image: Attach Disk Image]

   ---
3. Choose "Format Partition". [image: Format Partition]

   ---
4. Choose the partition name, choose `ext4` as the type, then click "Next". [image: Disk partition settings]

   ---
5. You will see something like this. Remember the "Backing File" value. [image: Backing File]

   ---
6. Run `sudo mkdir /path/to/mountpoint` to create your new disk partition's mountpoint.

   ---
7. Follow [this question's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/326533/mount-img-file-with-fstab) to mount your disk image on every boot automaticity.

   ---

These operations won't create a new physical partition, but they will solve your case.